# Kaminari ajax pagination only with prev and next button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I want to use Kaminari only with **prev** and **next** button.

I'm using the next helper:

```
<%= link_to_next_page @object, 'Next', :remote=>true %>
```

but this, show only a link with **Next** page.

I want to know how can I use the helpers **link_to_previous_page** and **link_to_next_page** toguether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually "link_to_next_page" helper only creates a link to the next page as the name of the method says. If you want to use prev and next buttons you should use the "paginate" helper. Ex:

You should check the 
[Kaminari Github Repository](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/tree/master/app/views/kaminari) README doc for more examples

Comment: Actually the link_to_previous_page helper was added to kaminari though it hasn't been built into the latest gem. https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/commit/39f829b616cc065e5effbc012f21ae3adab145e7#lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb, Anyway, you still can use it.

Comment: The Readme doc doesn't seem to have any good examples of using the paginate helper to show only `Prev` and `Next` style links.

It seems that paginate disables the next link when it has reached the last page, whereas the `link_to_next_page` helper doesn't seem to disable the link when it should.

If you know how to use the `paginate` method to show only the `next` and `prev` links could you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate the Kaminari views you'll need to edit. e.g. for bootstrap:

   `rails g kaminari:views bootstrap`
2. Rename app/views/kaminari/paginator.html.erb to _default_paginator.html.erb (note the added "_" at the beginning).
3. Create the following file: app/views/kaminari/_next_prev_paginator.html.erb. Copy/paste the contents of _default_paginator.html.erb in there, then delete the lines that display the page links.
4. Generate an initializer:

   `rails g kaminari:config`
5. In config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb, add the following code **before** "Kaminari.configure do":

   `Kaminari::Helpers::Tag.class_eval do
       def to_s(locals = {})
           @template.render :partial => "../views/kaminari/#{@theme}#{self.class.name.demodulize.underscore}", :locals => @options.merge(locals)
       end
   end`
6. In your view:

   `paginate @objects, :theme => "default_"`

   or

   `paginate @objects, :theme => "next_prev_"`

You can now style **_default_paginator.html.erb** and **_next_prev_paginator.html.erb** separately as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you are after but you can hide elements using CSS.
I use bootstrap with Kaminari and adding these to my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss will only show the previous and next buttons.

```
/* Removes the ellipses */
li.page.gap.disabled a {
  display:none;
}
/* Removes the last button */    
li.last.next a {
  display:none;
}
/* Removes first button */
li.first a {
  display:none;
}
/* Removes the active page */
li.page.active a {
  display:none;
}
```

It will apply this across the whole site though.